# SwipableContainer seems not responsive in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have implemented SwipableContainer and it seems not much responsive at the moment.

When I swipe the component sometimes it stuck or swipe very left. Also sometimes it will not allow to click the Swipe right buttons. see attached snapshots for your reference.

[image]

Sometimes it froze the container sliding. As well, when it dragging right side then container button seems not clickable. Once I drag center container little left, then right side container's button getting clickable.

In short overall behavior of swipable container is not upto the mark.

Any change I need to take place in my code? Please suggest.

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
hi.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
hi.setScrollable(false);
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(1,5);

Container tableHeaderContainer = new Container(tableLayout);
tableHeaderContainer.setScrollable(false);

for(int col=0;col<=4;col++){

    Button l1 = new Button("Header " + col+1);

    l1.setVerticalAlignment(Label.TOP);
    l1.setUIID("TableHeader");
    l1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        final InteractionDialog dlg = new InteractionDialog("Hello"); 
        dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        dlg.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label("Hello Dialog")); 
        Button close = new Button("Close"); 
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
                dlg.dispose(); 
            } 
        }); 
        dlg.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, close); 
        Dimension pre = dlg.getContentPane().getPreferredSize(); 
        dlg.showPopupDialog(new Rectangle((evt.getComponent().getX()+(evt.getComponent().getWidth())), (evt.getComponent().getY()+evt.getComponent().getHeight()), 
        evt.getComponent().getWidth(), evt.getComponent().getHeight()));
    }
    });

    TableLayout.Constraint constraint = ((TableLayout)tableHeaderContainer.getLayout()).createConstraint();
    constraint = setTableConstraint(constraint, col);
    tableHeaderContainer.addComponent(constraint,l1);
    } 

    hi.addComponent(tableHeaderContainer);

    Container tableContainerMain = new Container();
    tableContainerMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    tableContainerMain.setScrollableY(true);


    for(int row=0;row<=10;row++){
    Container tableContainer = new Container();
    tableContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    tableContainer.setScrollable(false);

    Button actionButton = new Button();
    tableLayout = new TableLayout(1,5);
    final Container rowContainer = new Container(tableLayout);

    Button editJobButton  = new Button();
    Button editJobButton1  = new Button();
    Button editJobButton2  = new Button();
    Button editJobButton3 = new Button();

    rowContainer.setFocusable(false);
    rowContainer.setLeadComponent(actionButton);

    actionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Dialog.show("actionButton", "actionButton", "OK","");
    }
    });

    for(int col=0;col<=6;col++){

        if(col==5){

            editJobButton = new Button();
            editJobButton.setIcon(theme.getImage("edit.png"));
            editJobButton.setPressedIcon(theme.getImage("edit-lg.png"));
            editJobButton.setDisabledIcon(theme.getImage("edit-gr.png"));
            editJobButton.setUIID("transparent_button_action_new");
            editJobButton.setVerticalAlignment(Label.TOP);
            editJobButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            }
            });

            editJobButton1 = new Button();
            editJobButton1.setIcon(theme.getImage("synch1.png"));
            editJobButton1.setPressedIcon(theme.getImage("synch-lg.png"));
            editJobButton1.setDisabledIcon(theme.getImage("synch-gr.png"));
            editJobButton1.setUIID("transparent_button_action_new");
            editJobButton1.setVerticalAlignment(Label.TOP);
            editJobButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                }
            });

            editJobButton2 = new Button();
            editJobButton2.setIcon(theme.getImage("map1.png"));
            editJobButton2.setPressedIcon(theme.getImage("map-lg.png"));
            editJobButton2.setUIID("transparent_button_action_new");
            editJobButton2.setVerticalAlignment(Label.TOP);
            editJobButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                }
            });

            editJobButton3 = new Button();
            editJobButton3.setIcon(theme.getImage("checkin.png"));
            editJobButton3.setPressedIcon(theme.getImage("checkin-lg.png"));
            editJobButton3.setDisabledIcon(theme.getImage("checkin-gr.png"));
            editJobButton3.setUIID("transparent_button_action_new");
            editJobButton3.setVerticalAlignment(Label.TOP);
            editJobButton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                }
            });
            }
        else{

            SpanLabel l2 = new SpanLabel(“This is testing text, This is testing text , This is testing text This is testing text " + (col+1));
            l2.setTextUIID("login_title");
            l2.setUIID("transparent");

            TableLayout.Constraint constraint1 = ((TableLayout)rowContainer.getLayout()).createConstraint();
            constraint1 = setTableConstraint(constraint1, col);
            rowContainer.addComponent(constraint1,l2);
        }
    } 

    SwipeableContainer swipeableContainer = new SwipeableContainer(null,BoxLayout.encloseX(editJobButton,editJobButton1,editJobButton2,editJobButton3), rowContainer);

    CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
    tableContainer.addComponent(c);
    tableContainer.addComponent(swipeableContainer);
    tableContainerMain.addComponent(tableContainer);



}
hi.addComponent(tableContainerMain);
hi.show();


public static Constraint setTableConstraint(Constraint constraint,int column){

    switch(column){
    case 0:
    constraint.setWidthPercentage(20);//job#
    break;
    case 1:
    constraint.setWidthPercentage(20);//Address
    break;
    case 2:
    constraint.setWidthPercentage(20);//Schedule Date
    break;
    case 3:
    constraint.setWidthPercentage(20);//Type
    break;
    case 4:
    constraint.setWidthPercentage(20);//Status
    break;

    default:
    constraint.setWidthPercentage(20);//else
    break;
    }

return constraint;

}
```

Comment: I'd like to know if this only happens when multi-touch is involved in some way as I see some potential issues related to multi-touch in `SwipeableContainer`.

Comment: @Shai- It happens even with single touch.

Comment: I was only able to reproduce that when a second finger touched somewhere, is there a specific process to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Shai - Can i have sample code? which works for you.

Comment: I used this sample, that you sent us. I was only able to reproduce an issue when both fingers touched the device at once.

Comment: @Shai- Did you check on device or simulator? It happens frequently on device only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `rowContainer` that you set to not focusable while having a lead component.

When you use `setFocusable(false)` on a container, you are asking the container not to respond to a touch event, combining this with setting a lead component to a button that can receive touch event will cause an unusual behaviour.

Also `rowContainer` doesn't contain `actionButton` which is the lead component.

Remove `rowContainer.setFocusable(false);`, leave `setLeadComponent`, and make sure `actionButton` is added to the container. Then check if this fix the problem.

Comment: @Diamond- I have removed rowContainer.setFocusable(false) and already added actionButton as setLeadComponent(actionButton). Is there anything else need to be check? Still issue is not solved.and yes it happens only while run this code on device.